# Problemas al ejecutar mi código con Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Estoy sacando un curso de Web Scrapy, pero al momento de ejecutar mi codigo como lo indica con el siguiente comando:

`scrapy runspider Extraccion_Scrapy.py -o video.csv -t csv`

Me arroja el siguiente error:

```
he documentation of the -o and -O options for more information.',)
      feeds = feed_process_params_from_cli(
    2021-07-09 16:34:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
    2021-07-09 16:34:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.3.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.2.0, Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)], pyO
    penSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021), cryptography 3.4.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
    2021-07-09 16:34:19 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
    Usage
    =====
      scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>
    runspider: error: File not found: Extraccion_Scrapy.py
```

Ya comprobé y Scrapy esta bien instalado busque en Internet y no encuentro a que se deba la falla, el código que deseo ejecutar es el siguiente:

```
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class Pregunta(Item):
    id = Field()
    pregunta = Field()
    descripcio = Field()


class StackOverFlowSpider(Spider):
    name = "MiprimerSpider"
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'
    }

    star_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions']

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        preguntas = sel.xpath('//div[@id="quetions"]//div[@class="question-summary"]')

        for pregunta in preguntas:
            item = ItemLoader(Pregunta(), pregunta)
            item.add_xpath('pregunta', './/h3/a/text()')
            item.add_xpath('descripcion', './/div[@class="excerpt"]/text()')
            item.add_value('id', 1)

            yield item.load_item()
```

Comment: Estás seguro de que escribiste bien el nombre del programa en el comando `scrapy runspider Extraccion_Scrapy.py -o video.csv -t csv`? Incluso una letra que debería estar en minuscula pero está en mayuscula podría causar que el script no sea encontrado.

Comment: También puede que el directorio de trabajo de tu cmd NO esté en la carpeta de tu script. Es decir, que a la izquierda de donde escribes el comando diga c:/users/tuusuario/desktop en lugar de c:/eldirectoriodetuscript. Estoy asumiendo que usas el cmd, perdón si me equivoco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer el problema era que moví los archivos a otra carpeta y al hora de ejecutar el comando en Pycharm no me percate que seguía con la dirección vieja.